# Site can't be reached Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem with the chrome browser.  I am always getting the error:

```
Site can't be reached
```

I am using `valet`. I have tried to reinstall the `brew` and its services (php, database), chrome itself. I also tried to reinstall valet, change domain from `dev` to `app` but nothing worked. I am getting this issue only on chrome. However, when I start the local server like: `php artisan serve`, the site works.
Everything is woking as expected on all other browsers. I tried to get the content from the page using curl like so:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 63.0.3239.108" vform.app
```

And I got the content of the page correctly.

Comment: There's a lot of background missing here. Tried other browsers? curl? What other components could be tagged or described to help people understand what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for response. I will edit the answer and post more details